# Convertir un parrafo bs64 a string y leerlo linea por linea en C# .Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, txt

Estoy tratando de convertir un texto en **BASE64** a **String** , cuando se realice la conversión se debe leer este párrafo y separarlo linea por linea.

La conversion del parrafo a String ya la tengo y lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
private string Base64ToString(string base64String)
{
    byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
    string decodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
    return decodedString;
}
```

Este me devuelve el siguiente String y este es el que tengo que leer linea por linea:

```
120210218007000009001562642PRUEBA A.P.S. S.A.                                                                            
500000003182120773010100                                                                                                
6900838458       EUREKA GUAVIARE 000010078611837396     20210202000001860000000000036400001130000001                    
637239274        ARACELY QUINTERO000010078611849457     20210102000001860000000000113600001130000002                    
621672001        MARIA ROSMIRA GO000010078611437021     20210202000001860000000000113600001130000003                    
637800499        RAQUEL MEJIA DE 000010078611291574     20210102000001860000000000113600001130000004                    
670722724        JOSE HERNAN RAMI000010078611312622     20210202000001860000000000113600001130000005                    
652871276        NINI YOHANA VARO000010078611852353     20210102000001860000000000161300001130000006                    
6474084          PEDRO ANTONIO MO000010078611550549     20210102000001860000000000113600001130000007                    
621953789        MARIA YOLANDA CA000010078611375911     20210202000001860000000000113600001130000008                    
624322185        MARIA ARSENIA VA000010078611557697     20210102000001860000000000113600001130000009                    
61037322825      JUAN GUILLERMO H000010078611839077     20210202000001860000000000113600001130000010                    
693290752        ARTEMO JIMENEZ J000010078611375693     20210202000001860000000000113600001531000011                    
61042774280      CARLOS ARLEY OSO000010078611851292     20210102000001860000000000113600001531000012                    
6900101681       FUNDACION SOCIAL000010078611837963     20210202000001860000000000113600001531000013                    
612616960        LUIS EDUARDO FAN000010078611847568     20210102000001860000000000113600001531000014                    
613702117        HERNAN ALONSO GO000010078611498574     20210202000001860000000000113600001531000015                    
623779639        MARIA SONIA HERN000010078611838853     20210202000001860000000000128800001531000016                    
691510572        JOSE DAVID NIGRI000010078611840872     20210102000001860000000000113600001631000017                    
8000017000017000000000191690000
```

He intentado lo siguiente, para leer el texto linea por linea, pero no se el por que no realiza la separación:

En la variable lstBs64 llega el texto en **BS64**:

```
 string[] lineas = Base64ToString(lstBs64).Split(Environment.NewLine);
```

Como pueden ver tengo un método **`Base64ToString`**  el cual convierte el **string Bs64** a **string** y a la vez trato de separarlo linea por linea con **`Split(Environment.NewLine)`** pero no funciona.

Quisiera saber si hay otra forma y que estoy haciendo mal.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algo como esto:

```
    string contenido = String.Empty;
    string texto = Base64ToString(lstBs64);
    contenido = File.ReadAllText(texto);
    string[] lineas = contenido.Split(Environment.NewLine);
    foreach (string linea in lineas)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(linea);
    }
```

Comment: El File.ReadAllText no funciona ya que no estoy leyendo un archivo solo texto , y al quitarlo y dejar que se haga el split al texto no funciona sigue, trayendo el texo completo

Comment: Funciono la separación de lineas cambiando el **Enviroment.NewLine** por **"\n"** , sigo sin entender por que no funciona el NewLine